# Broadcast the real time MySQL database table data

Tags: mysql, signalr, sqldependency, broadcasting

I need to broadcast the real time database table to my web application (Asp.net).

I know I can implement it using SignalR and SqlDepedency. But the issue is my database is MySQL. I have done lot of research on how to implement it using MySQL. But didn't find anything useful.

Please guide me if there is something I can try with MySQL to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid SqlDep. anyway. I always recommend publishing database changes on a service bus and let signalr pick it up.  This way you can fire state changes anyware in your domain and signalr can pick it up

Check this library out to abstract signalr from your backend bus (I'm the author)

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Comment: your demo site is death