# Add a new label with the inserted text when the text is inserted on my database on Xamarin Forms C#

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried looking triggers up for mysql but from what I can tell its no use for me here. I would like the labels to be one on top of the other. I would appreciate some help
EDIT: Because what I want might not be clear,
Whenever I insert a text on my database I want to create a label on my application with the the text I just inserted. For example when I insert "username" I want a label to be created and have the Text value equal to username. Then when I insert "password" I want another label under it with the text = "password" and so on with a third and fourth label...

Comment: Can you explain more detailed what you want to achieve? It it's current state, the question could mean many different things.

Comment: Whenever I insert a text on my database I want to create a label on my application with the the text I just inserted. For example when I insert "username" I want a label to be created and have the Text value equal to username. Then when I insert "password" I want another label under it with the text = "password" and so on

Comment: You can notify your ViewModel to reload the data when something is added, or just add the new item to your List.

Comment: But how do I do that whenever something is inserted in my mySQL database? And is there a way to add multiple Labels on my Main Page via c#?

Comment: Somewhere it is added, at this point you can send a Message with MessagingCenter for example. About the labels, I would put a `ListView` onto your site which displays a `Label` in it's `ItemTemplate`. Sorry without more information, it's hard to describe it more detailed. You'll have to show some code

Comment: do you mean a local database on your device?  Or a remote database located on a server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292906/sqldependency-on-a-mariadb-mysql-database or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697096/broadcast-the-real-time-mysql-database-table-data or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057725/how-to-push-mysql-database-data-to-a-mvc-net-web-application or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435603/mysql-push-notification

Comment: A remote database, I just want to retrieve multiple data and put that data as text for my labels. I keep trying to use datareader but it only gives me one of my many rows. No this is not a duplicate @Jason

Comment: How is data being inserted?  Are there multiple instances of the client inserting data, and all clients need to refresh when data is updated?

Comment: From a mysql command, no there are not. Yeah they need to refresh I guess. I just need to know a way I can get the data of a whole column and then use it however I want